Append to a QList using move, not copy
I am creating a QList of large objects: QList< MyLargeObject >
I first create the large object, and then I append it to my QList.  I believe this is making a copy of the MyLargeObject.  Is it possible to move (not copy) the object onto the Qlist?  (Without creating MyLargeObject on the heap and using QList<MyLargeObject*>

It doesn't look like the container supports moving object into it.  Do you need to use QList?  Would a std::vector work in its place?

Yes - a std::vector should work fine

Replace myList.append(myLargeObject) with myList.append(std::move(myLargeObject)) and you are good to go (assuming myLargeObject is not const, one cannot move const objects).

What happens if the original MyLargeObject is created on the stack?  When the method exits will the object be lost?  Do I need to create the  MyLargeObject on the heap, and then use the move method?
